# How do I solve Class Cast Exception when it comes to Unit Testing?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I have been generating Test Cases for some classes using a tool called Diff Blue. Now Diff Blue is an AI tool that can generate multiple Test Cases for some functions. I have a particular class for which I have generated Test Cases using Diff Blue but one Test Case has failed. My main goal is to get all of the Test Cases to pass. The Test Case I'm working on is for the below class with function getDashboardById.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
@Service
@Slf4j
public class DashboardServiceImpl implements DashboardService {

    private final DashboardRepository dashboardRepository;
    private final PlatformDataExtractHistoryService platformDataExtractHistoryService;
    private final ShopifyService shopifyService;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    /**
     * Get Dashboard by its id
     *
     * @param id dashboard id
     * @return DashboardGetDto
     */
    @Override
    public DashboardGetDto getDashboardById(String id) {
        Dashboard dashboard = dashboardRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(GlobalErrorUtils.DASHBOARD_NOT_FOUND_404));
        log.info("Get dashboard details by id: {}", id);

        // convert entity to DTO
        return modelMapper.map(dashboard, DashboardGetDto.class);
    }
```

Diffblue has generated 3 Test Cases for the function getDashboardById. Two of the Test Cases passed while one failed. My goal is to get it to pass too. The below code is the code of the failed test case.

```
void testGetDashboardById3() {
        DashboardGetDto dashboardGetDto = new DashboardGetDto();
        when(dashboardRepository.findById((String) any())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        when(modelMapper.map((Object) any(), any())).thenReturn("Map");
        when(modelMapper.map((Object) any(), (Class<DashboardGetDto>) any())).thenReturn(dashboardGetDto);
        assertThrows(ResourceNotFoundException.class, () -> dashboardServiceImpl.getDashboardById("42"));
        verify(dashboardRepository).findById((String) any());
        verify(modelMapper).map((Object) any(), (Class<Object>) any());
    }
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that I'm getting a Class Cast Exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.unicorn.dashboard.dto.dashboard.DashboardGetDto (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.unicorn.dashboard.dto.dashboard.DashboardGetDto is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

    at com.unicorn.dashboard.serviceImpl.DashboardServiceImplTest.testGetDashboardById3(DashboardServiceImplTest.java:127)
```

Now I do understand that this occurs when you try to cast a class of one type to another. But what I'm struggling to understand is where the error is being generated and how do I solve it since this is a Test Case. The Error points at line 127 which is in the above Test Function testGetDashboardById3. For reference I'll give the line below

```
when(modelMapper.map((Object) any(), (Class<DashboardGetDto>) any())).thenReturn(dashboardGetDto);
```

Now what I don't understand is that where exactly in the above line is the Cast occurring and what must be changed in order to get the Test Case working?

Edit

I have edited my code as per the answers and displayed it below. However there is an error within the code. What necessary changes must be done to fix the error?

[image]

When I hover over the highlighted area I get this message

[image]

Comment: NB. `(String)any()` is a very complicated way of writing `anyString()`.

Comment: What is the signature of `ModelMapper#map`?

Comment: ` when(modelMapper.map((Object) any(), any())).thenReturn("Map");` results in a `String` being returned instead of an `DashboardGetDto` leading to an exception.

Answer (score 0):

`when(modelMapper.map((Object) any(), any())).thenReturn("Map");` matches any second argument. You want to mock method [`<D> D map(Object source, Class<D> destinationType)`](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/ModelMapper.html#map-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) which you would call as `map(input, String.class)` and `map(input, DashboardGetDto.class)` in your production code. Therefore, you want to set up this method as:

```
when(modelMapper.map(any(), eq(String.class)))
        .thenReturn("Map");
when(modelMapper.map(any(), eq(DashboardGetDto.class)))
        .thenReturn(dashboardGetDto);
```

to select the correct overloads. Your test was matching calls such as `map(input, new DashboardGetDto())`, which returns `void`.

Note that `ArgumentMatchers#any()` is already generic, so you don't have to cast the return value. You can either use `ArgumentMatchers.<Object>any()` or `any(Object.class)`.

Important to note is that the Java runtime cannot distinguish between `Class<X>` and `Class<Y>` (or `List<A>` and `List<B>`). For the JVM, both are of type `Class` (or `List`, respectively). Your first `when` call was already matching all calls to your mock.

Comment: Hey @Knittl I have done exactly as you said. However there is some kind of Coding error which I'm not sure of. I have updated my question above and you can see that the line is highlighted in red. What changes must be done in order to fix it?

Comment: @SaifThaha that's odd. It looks like `modelMapper.map(Object, String)` returns a void or expects a void? `anyString` is non-generic and returns a string, so I'm really confused by this message. I'll have to try it myself with a real compiler

Comment: Oh right, it is indeed `void ModelMapper#map(Object, Object)`. The form with a return value is `<D> D map(Object, Source<D>)`. You want to have `ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any()`, but pay attention to my last paragraph: this information is usually not available at runtime due to _type erasure_. I'm not sure if Mockito will be able to discern those two calls (`Class<String>` vs `Class<DashboardGetDto>`).

Comment: So then my code has to be like ```when(modelMapper.map((Object)any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())).thenReturn("Map");``` ?

Comment: @SaifThaha I haven't had my coffee yet. See my updated answer, you want to match equal classes, not instances of the class.